# Basic iterator supporting vector implementation

Tags: c++, iterator, vectors

On the fly, I just implemented this iterator supporting vector class to understand how range-based for loop works.
It's really basic but let me know what can be improved.

*Vector.h*

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <stdexcept>

template <typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
    /* The iterator */
    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        Iterator(const Vector<T> *vector, int nIndex);
        const T &operator*() const;
        Iterator &operator++();
        bool operator!=(const Iterator &other) const;

    private:
        const Vector<T> *m_pVector;
        int m_nIndex = -1;
    };

public:
    // constructors
    Vector() = default;
    explicit Vector(int nSize);

    ~Vector();

    void insert(const T &value);

    int size() const;
    const T &operator[](int nIndex) const;

    Iterator begin() const;
    Iterator end() const;

private:
    T *m_pData = nullptr;
    int m_nSize = 0;
    int m_nCapacity = 0;
};

/*
 * Vector methods
 **/
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int nCapacity)
{
    m_nCapacity = nCapacity;
    m_pData = new T[m_nCapacity];
}

template <typename T>
Vector<T>::~Vector()
{
    delete m_pData;
    m_nSize = 0;
    m_nCapacity = 0;
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::insert(const T &value)
{
    if (m_nSize == m_nCapacity)
    {
        if (m_nCapacity == 0)
            m_nCapacity = 1;

        m_nCapacity *= 2;

        // allocate 2x larger memory
        auto pNewMemory = new T[m_nCapacity];

        // copy data to there
        for (auto idx = 0; idx < m_nSize; ++idx)
            pNewMemory[idx] = m_pData[idx];

        delete m_pData;
        m_pData = pNewMemory;
    }

    // insert the new element
    m_pData[m_nSize] = value;
    ++m_nSize;
}

template <typename T>
int Vector<T>::size() const
{
    return m_nSize;
}

template <typename T>
const T &Vector<T>::operator[](int nIndex) const
{
    if (nIndex >= m_nSize)
        throw std::exception("Index out of range");

    return m_pData[nIndex];
}

template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::Iterator Vector<T>::begin() const
{
    return Vector<T>::Iterator{ this, 0 };
}

template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::Iterator Vector<T>::end() const
{
    return Vector<T>::Iterator{ this, m_nSize };
}

/*
 * Iterator methods
 **/
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Iterator::Iterator(const Vector<T> *pVector, int nIndex)
    : m_pVector(pVector)
    , m_nIndex(nIndex)
{
}

template <typename T>
const T &Vector<T>::Iterator::operator*() const
{
    return m_pVector->operator[](m_nIndex);
}

template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::Iterator &Vector<T>::Iterator::operator++()
{
    ++m_nIndex;
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
bool Vector<T>::Iterator::operator!=(const Vector<T>::Iterator &other) const
{
    return m_nIndex != other.m_nIndex;
}

#endif // !VECTOR_H
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Vector.h"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Vector<int> vector;
        vector.insert(8);
        vector.insert(3);
        vector.insert(1);
        vector.insert(7);
        vector.insert(2);

        for (auto i : vector)
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### The range-based `for` loop

This works via the `begin()` and `end()` **functions**.
So for any class `X` if there are stand alone functions `begin(X&)` and `end(X&)` the range based `for` will work. Normally this will default to the `std::begin()` and `std::end()` but if you have written explicit versions of these functions in the same namespace as `X` these will be used.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Y
{
    class X
    {
        public:
            char data[14] = "This is text";
    };

    char* begin(X& obj) {
        return obj.data;
    }

    char* end(X& obj) {
        return obj.data + 10;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Y::X   x;
    for(auto const& a: x) {
        std::cout << a;
    }
}
```

OK. So what happens if you don't write your own `begin()` and `end()` functions?

In this case it will use the standard versions of these functions. `std::begin()` which will call the `begin()` method on the object and `std::end()` which will call the `end()` method on the object.

Example 2:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace Y
{
    class X
    {
            char data[14] = "This is text";
        public:
            char* begin() {
                return data;
            }

            char* end() {
                return data + 10;
            }
    };
}

int main()
{
    Y::X   x;
    for(auto const& a: x) {
        std::cout << a;
    }
}
```

### How to think of range based for

You can think of ranged based for as a compiler shortcut.

```
for(<Type> <Var> : <Obj>) {
    <CODE>
}
```

Is just short hand for:

```
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    auto __end = end(<Obj>);

    for(auto __loop = begin(<Obj>); __loop != __end; ++__loop) {
        <Type> <Var> = *__loop;
        <CODE>
    }
}
```

### Implementation of Iterators

The implementation of an iterator is based on the "Iterator Concept". There are actually five types of iterator in C++. But since you are using vector as your example implementation we should consider the "Random Access Iterator Concept".

To qualify as a random access iterator you have to uphold a specific contract. Here is some documentation on it.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator

Not only does the iterator need to define certain methods (with specific requirements on how they work together). But your type also needs to define certain types via `std::iterator_traits`.

#### Types

You need to define the following types:

- value_type:
  When the iterator is de-referenced this is the type you get.
- difference_type:
  When you subtract two iterators this is the type of the result
- pointer:
  A type that points at type `value_type`
- reference:
  A type that can be used as a reference to a value of type `value_type`
- iterator_category:
  A type that represents the [category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_tags) of the iterator.

So you could have written your own specialization of the `iterator_traits` class

```
namespace std
{
    template<typename T>
    class iterator_traits<Vector<T>::Iterator>
    {
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference  = T&;
        using iteratory_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    };
}
```

But that is a little bit like actual hard work. The designers of the STL actually got smart and the default implementation of this type refer back to the iterator type to get these types. So you can define these types in your iterator (and not define a specialization of the `iterator_traits` class).

Rather do this:

```
template<typename T>
class Vector
{
    class Iterator
    {
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference  = T&;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
    };
    ....
}
```

Note: If you follow the advice above and use a pointer as your iterator. The `iterator_traits` for pointer types are well defined in the standard and no work is required.

#### Properties of an Iterator

The basic properties of an iterator are:

- Default Constructible    *** Currently not supported.
- Copy Constructible
- Copy Assignable
- Destructible
- Swappable      *** Currently not supported.
- Equality Comparable  *** Currently not supported (you need ==)
- objects returned via de-referencing need to be mutable (not supported)

Supported actions for a random access iterator:

```
*i                  // returns the current value
*i  = v             // Assign value `v` to the value dererenced.
++i                 // increments the iterator (returns a reference)
--i                 // See above
i++                 // increments the iterator (but returns a reference to the original)
i--                 // See above
*i++                // returns the current value and increments the iterator
*i--                // See above

i += n              // Moves the iterator forward
i -= n              // Same as last one
i + n               // Creates a new iterator moved forward from i
n + i               // Same as last one
i - n               // Same as last one

i1 - i2             // returns the distance between the iterators.

i[n]                // returns the item n steps forward from this iterator.
i->m                // Access the member `m` referenced by i

i1 <  i2            // Compare iterators
i1 >  i2
i1 <= i2
i1 >= i2
i1 == i2
i1 != i2
```

OK So I have dumped an all lot of requirements on iterators here. But it is not as bad as it seems. Have a look at an iterator I built for a stack overflow question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1120224/14065

This iterator is only a forward iterator (so it has fewer requirements). But it shows you how to implement the main basic requirements very quickly. The rest should not be too hard to implement for random accesses iterator.

Got bored so here:

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    using pointer    = T*;
    using reference  = T&;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    Iterator():                    v(nullptr), i(0) {}   
    Iterator(Vector<T>* v, int i): v(v),       i(i) {}
    // Default Copy/Move Are Fine.
    // Default Destructor fine.

    reference       operator*()             {return (*v)[i];}
    const reference operator*()       const {return (*v)[i];}
    pointer         operator->()            {return &((*v)[i]);}
    const pointer   operator->()      const {return &((*v)[i]);}
    reference       operator[](int m)       {return (*v)[i + m];}
    const reference operator[](int m) const {return (*v)[i + m];}
    

    Iterator& operator++()       {++i;return *this;}
    Iterator& operator--()       {--i;return *this;}
    Iterator  operator++(int)    {Iterator r(*this);++i;return r;}
    Iterator  operator--(int)    {Iterator r(*this);--i;return r;}

    Iterator& operator+=(int n)  {i += n;return *this;}
    Iterator& operator-=(int n)  {i -= n;return *this;}

    Iterator operator+(int n)   const {Iterator r(*this);return r += n;}
    Iterator operator-(int n)   const {Iterator r(*this);return r -= n;}

    difference_type operator-(Iterator const& r) const {return i - r.i;}

    // Note: comparing iterator from different containers
    //       is undefined behavior so we don't need to check
    //       if they are the same container.
    bool operator<(Iterator const& r)  const {return i <  r.i;}
    bool operator<=(Iterator const& r) const {return i <= r.i;}
    bool operator>(Iterator const& r)  const {return i >  r.i;}
    bool operator>=(Iterator const& r) const {return i >= r.i;}
    bool operator!=(const Iterator &r) const {return i != r.i;}
    bool operator==(const Iterator &r) const {return i == r.i;}

private:
    Vector<T>* v;
    int        i;
};
```

### The Container.

Since you were asking about Iterators I will not give input on the Vector just yet (but lets say it needs work).

I have written a couple of articles on implementing the vector that you can have a look at.

http://lokiastari.com/series/

Comment: how is `obj` passed to `char *begin(X& obj)`?

Comment: The definition of the range based for is to use `Koenig lookup` (also know as ADNL) to see if there is an appropriate version of the function `begin()`. If the compiler does not find an appropriate function it will use `std::begin()` instead.

Comment: @user3132457: I have added a new section `How to think of range based for` to explain how to think of the range based for.

Comment: Really useful. Should it not be `size_t i;` ?

Comment: @OliverSchonrock You can make that argument. But I prefer using `int`. Even if `int` is only 32 bit this means we could index 4G worth of memory (8G with std::size_t). I believe the standards committee fucked up by making `std::size_t` unsigned (even they have mentioned it was probably a mistake but its too late now to change back).

Comment: I agree size_t was a mistake, I think most agree. However, while that's what it is, should we create a fractured world? 

I use int for my loop indexes for local code (if I can put up with / suppress the conversion warnings) for more "library code" (which is arguably what this suggested iterator implementation is) one could say there is a better case for sticking with the "wrong" size_t while that's what the rest of the STL has.

Answer (score 12):

### Use `delete[]`

You are allocating an array of objects with `new[]`, but attempting to delete them with `delete`, which results in undefined behavior. You should delete the array with `delete[]` to ensure that your code functions properly. Do this in both `Vector<T>::~Vector()` and `Vector<T>::insert()`.

### Implement your `Iterator`s as pointers under-the-hood

Since your data is stored sequentially, it makes sense to implement your `Iterator` members as a simple `T const *` rather than a pointer to the parent `Vector<T>` and an index. This cuts down the size of your `Iterator`, and avoids the awkward `m_nIndex = -1` state. You can replace the `Iterator`'s internals in this way without changing its interface.

(As a side note, the range-based `for`-loop would still function if you completely removed the `Iterator` class and just returned `T const *` from `Vector<T>::begin()` and `Vector<T>::end()`. I know this is not what you asked, but thought you might like to know! [Example](http://cpp.sh/8fzte))

### Construct member variables in the constructor initializer list

You are already using a member initializer list for your `Iterator` class, so you should do the same for `Vector<T>`

```
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int nCapacity)
    : m_nCapacity(nCapacity)
    , m_pData(new T[nCapacity])
{
}
```

### Use `size_t` for container size

A small detail, but using `size_t` instead of `int` for `Vector<T>::size` more closely resembles the standard library's containers. It is a very standard way of representing sizes.

Comment: Actually, many consider unsigned integer types for sizes one of the bigger mistakes of the standard library because of how they interact with signed values (e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < vec.size() - 5; ++i)` contains a serious bug). Unsigned size values got introduces as a hack/workaround to allow one more bit worth of possible storage space. It cannot be officially fixed now, because it would break backwards compatibility. But for new containers? There's no precedent, so I'd actually suggest using signed values for sizes (we don't need that extra bit for modern 64.bit architectures).

Comment: @hoffmale, do you have any guarantee that the code will only ever be built for "*modern 64.bit architectures*"?  16-bit `int` hasn't just stopped existing, you know.

Comment: @TobySpeight: Well, yes, 8-bit and 16-bit platforms still do exist. However, most of those have some kind of advanced addressing mode to allow for addressing more than 256 Bytes/65.536 Bytes respectively (e.g. `far` pointers). Unless your usage scenario requires you to have 50%+ of the addressable memory in a container of 1 Byte sized objects, that one extra bit of size information isn't needed. And if **that** is your usage scenario, it might be advisable to rethink your platform choice and/or write a specialized container, since you're likely to have very harsh memory constraints anyways.

Comment: Assuming of course that the number of address bits is the same as the bits of the intended `size` variable (i.e. this becomes a non-issue if `size` is a `int32_t`, but there is only a 24-bit address space).

Comment: My point is that `int` isn't necessarily wide enough to represent the size of the container - you might need `long`, for example (common on machines with 16-bit word size and 32-bit addressing for example).  `std::size_t` is automatically the right width for the size of any object.

Comment: @hoffmale: the standard is `size_t` and the `for` should be `for(size_t i` or `vector<..>::size_type`or rather avoided alltogether by using `begin()` and `end() - 5`. Most compilers will also warn you when you compare signed to unsigned. Using `int` brings in more problems then it solves.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I never said anything about using `int` for `Vector::size`. If I had to specify it, I'd think of `std::ptrdiff_t`, unless some weird platform is involved. (Note that `std::size_t` and `std::ptrdiff_t` are still 16bit on 16bit systems with a segmented memory model). // @firda: I never said I recommend that code. (Also, `end() - 5` invokes undefined behavior under the same conditions the original loop does.) One way to write it correctly would be `for(auto i = 0u; i + 5 < vec.size(); ++i)` (would even work with `auto i = 0`).

Comment: Sorry @hoffmale - I'd formed an image in my mind that you'd said `int` when you hadn't.  I was wrong!

Comment: @firda: (continued) Just using an unsigned loop counter variable doesn't fix the bug (after all, it's the subtraction that causes it in this case, not the comparison!). And this was just an easy, obvious example to highlight the problems with unsigned size types. There are far more devious cases in the wild, and even those compiler warnings might not recognize them (after all, comparing unsigned to unsigned is fine, at least most of the time).

Comment: @hoffmale: I am not arguing against signed size type, it has its benefits (like `length` in C#), but against you suggesting that new containers should use it (as you wrote in your very first comment). No, that would be a mess. I can imagine having `std:size_t` signed, but that would be platform/architecture/implementation-dependent and the standard (or at least docs I use) already specify it is unsigned. Tool late to change it.

Answer (score 6):

In [cariehl's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/202159/151754) you've already learned about implementing your iterator as a pointer, which would simplify the class significantly. Iterators were originally designed to mimic pointers, a pointer is an iterator. But it's nice to have a dedicated class as your iterator, because C++ is all about types, you want to let the compiler check your types and give error messages if things don't match.

#### Style

`class Vector` is a common name, and likely to clash. So is `VECTOR_H` as an include guard. I would suggest that you always use namespaces, even if you don't think you'll re-use the code later in a larger project.

In C++, it is preferred to write `const T& value` (or even `T const& value`) rather than `const T &value`. The `&` is part of the type, and so should be close to the type, not to the variable name.

#### Constructor

Your constructor `Vector(int nCapacity)` sets the capacity, and leaves `size` at 0. This is not the behavior of `std::vector`, and therefore could be confusing. If you call `Vector(0)` you'll allocate an array of size 0, which is UB (as far as I know).

#### Destructor

Your destructor:

> ```
> template <typename T>
> Vector<T>::~Vector()
> {
>     delete m_pData;
>     m_nSize = 0;
>     m_nCapacity = 0;
> }
> ```

sets member variable values. This is unnecessary, as the destructor is called when the object ceases to exist. There is no need to leave it in a consistent state. You also have the bug that [cariehl's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/202159/151754) mentioned: `delete[] m_pData`.

However, ideally you don't have a destructor at all. If you store your pointer in a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead of `T*`, you can skip writing a destructor.

By not writing a destructor, the compiler will automatically generate a move assignment and a move constructor for you. Currently, your class is not copyable or movable. To make it copyable, you'll have to explicitly write a copy constructor and assignment operator, since `std::unique_ptr` is not copyable.

#### Insertion

The `Vector::insert` method uses a loop to copy data:

> ```
> for (auto idx = 0; idx < m_nSize; ++idx)
>     pNewMemory[idx] = m_pData[idx];
> ```

This could be inefficient. For one, you should be moving the data, not copying it. For `T==int` it doesn't matter, but for more complex types it does. You can use the algorithm `std::move` effectively to move the data (which is implemented as a fast `memcpy` if data is trivially copyable):

```
std::move(m_pData, m_pData + m_nSize, pNewMemory);
```

You'll need to include `<algorithm>` for this.

Now you need to change the signature for your `insert(const T &value)` function to be `insert(T value)`. Then:

> ```
> m_pData[m_nSize] = value;
> ```

becomes:

```
m_pData[m_nSize] = std::move(value);
```

Now the copy is made when you call the function, rather than inside the function. The advantage is that if the value used when calling the function is temporary, or you explicitly `std::move` it, no copy will be made at all.

#### Exceptions

> ```
> throw std::exception("Index out of range");
> ```

is not legal C++, as [`std::exception`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) doesn't have such a constructor. Instead, use `std::runtime_error` or `std::logic_error`, or even `std::range_error`, which is derived from `std::runtime_error` and used by the standard library exactly for this type of error.

Comment: @TobySpeight what do you mean by "pair f(const T&) with f(T&&)"?

Comment: @TobySpeight: thanks for the corrections. I was sloppy.

Comment: @user3132457, sorry for being too terse; I meant an overloaded pair: e.g. `f(const T&)` (which copies from its argument) and `f(T&&)` (which moves from its argument).  It's simpler to write a single function `f(T)` (move from the argument), as that reduces duplication.

Comment: how can i put the updated code on here?

Comment: @user3132457: If you want, you can make a new question with updated code, to get further feedback (add a link to this question). Otherwise you can post your updated code as an answer to just show it off.

Comment: @user3132457, here's some helpful advice that mentions how to present your updated code: *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: okay i added the updated code as an answer

Comment: `This is unnecessary, as the destructor is called when the object ceases to exist. There is no need to leave it in a consistent state.` Yes, except if you want to make debugging easier for yourself. If you are for example constructing the object in a pre-allocated memory block, the memory is still accessible even after the destructor has been called. As such it is a way to tell if destruction was successful or not. This for example aids in debugging custom container classes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for answers. I have added/changed my code based on your advice. Please find the updated version below.

*Vector.h*

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>

namespace Simple
{

template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using pointer = T *;
    using reference = T &;

public:
    /* The iterator */
    class Iterator
    {
        using value_type = T;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using pointer = T *;
        using reference = T &;
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    public:
        Iterator() = default;
        Iterator(T *pData) : m_ptr(pData) {}

        reference       operator*()                     { return *m_ptr; }
        const reference &operator*()            const   { return *m_ptr; }
        pointer         operator->()                    { return m_ptr; }
        const pointer   operator->()            const   { return m_ptr; }
        reference       operator[](int offset)          { return m_ptr[offset]; }
        const reference operator[](int offset)  const   { return m_ptr[offset]; }

        Iterator &operator++()      { ++m_ptr; return *this; }
        Iterator &operator--()      { --m_ptr; return *this; }
        Iterator operator++(int)    { Iterator it(*this); ++m_ptr; return *this; }
        Iterator operator--(int)    { Iterator it(*this); --m_ptr; return *this; }

        Iterator &operator+=(int offset) { m_ptr += offset; return *this; }
        Iterator &operator-=(int offset) { m_ptr -= offset; return *this; }

        Iterator operator+(int offset) const { Iterator it(*this); return it += offset; }
        Iterator operator-(int offset) const { Iterator it(*this); return it -= offset; }

        difference_type operator-(const Iterator &other) const { return m_ptr - other.m_ptr; }

        // Note: comparing iterator from different containers
        //       is undefined behavior so we don't need to check
        //       if they are the same container.
        bool operator<  (const Iterator &other) const   { return m_ptr < other.m_ptr; }
        bool operator<= (const Iterator &other) const   { return m_ptr <= other.m_ptr; }
        bool operator>  (const Iterator &other) const   { return m_ptr > other.m_ptr; }
        bool operator>= (const Iterator &other) const   { return m_ptr >= other.m_ptr; }
        bool operator== (const Iterator &other) const   { return m_ptr == other.m_ptr; }
        bool operator!= (const Iterator &other) const   { return m_ptr != other.m_ptr; }

    private:
        T *m_ptr{ nullptr };
    };

public:
    // constructors
    Vector() = default;
    explicit Vector(std::size_t nCapacity);

    void insert(value_type value);

    std::size_t size() const;

    reference operator[](std::size_t nIndex);
    const reference operator[](std::size_t nIndex) const;

    Iterator begin();
    Iterator end();

private:
    void resizeIfRequired();
    void detectCapacity();
    void allocateMemory();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<value_type[]> m_pData{ nullptr };
    std::size_t m_nSize = 0;
    std::size_t m_nCapacity = 0;
};

/*
 * Vector methods
 **/
template <typename T>
Vector<T>::Vector(std::size_t nCapacity)
{
    if (nCapacity > 0)
    {
        m_nCapacity = nCapacity;
        m_pData = std::make_unique<value_type[]>(nCapacity);
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::insert(value_type value)
{
    resizeIfRequired();

    // insert the new element
    m_pData[m_nSize] = std::move(value);
    ++m_nSize;
}

template <typename T>
std::size_t Vector<T>::size() const
{
    return m_nSize;
}

template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::reference Vector<T>::operator[](std::size_t nIndex)
{
    if (nIndex >= m_nSize)
        throw std::exception("Index out of range");

    return m_pData[nIndex];
}

template <typename T>
typename const Vector<T>::reference Vector<T>::operator[](std::size_t nIndex) const
{
    return operator[](nIndex);
}

template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::Iterator Vector<T>::begin()
{
    return Vector<T>::Iterator{ m_pData.get() };
}

template <typename T>
typename Vector<T>::Iterator Vector<T>::end()
{
    return Vector<T>::Iterator{ m_pData.get() + m_nSize };
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::resizeIfRequired()
{
    if (m_nSize == m_nCapacity)
    {
        detectCapacity();
        allocateMemory();
    }
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::detectCapacity()
{
    if (m_nCapacity == 0)
    {
        m_nCapacity = 1;
        m_pData = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_nCapacity);
    }
    else
        m_nCapacity *= 2;
}

template <typename T>
void Vector<T>::allocateMemory()
{
    // allocate new memory
    auto pNewMemory = new T[m_nCapacity];

    // move data to there
    std::move(m_pData.get(), m_pData.get() + m_nSize, pNewMemory);

    m_pData.reset(pNewMemory);
}

} // namespace Simple

#endif // !VECTOR_H
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Vector.h"

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Simple::Vector<int> vector;
        vector.insert(8);
        vector.insert(3);
        vector.insert(1);
        vector.insert(7);
        vector.insert(2);

        for (auto i : vector)
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When we suggested you write the iteration using a pointer, we didn’t mean storing a pointer to the `Vector` object, but rather a pointer to the data inside the vector. All you need to store inside your iterator is a single value of type `pointer`. Try that out, you’ll see how much simpler the iterator becomes.

Comment: Oh right, I just updated the code and now I see how much simpler it is.

Comment: I have made a few changes to your `Iterator` class so you can see what I meant. You don't need to store a pointer the data and an index. A single pointer can do it all. Click on the "edited" link to see the changes. Feel free to revert the edits, I just thought editing your code directly would be the easiest way to show what I meant. I hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Only one thing seems incorrect to me - in comparison operators the values of pointers are compared, not actual indexes.

Comment: Yes, that is the exact same behavior, though. If the two pointers point to addresses within the same memory block, then the comparisons and pointer arithmetic do exactly as you would want.

Comment: but how? say i have two local var pointers, the addresses of them are different based on which one was created earlier,  but the values they contain don't have to follow this rule.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... When you compare iterators, you compare the locations they're pointing to. Say you have `it1=vector.begin()`, which points to `vector[0]`, then `it2=it1+3` points to `vector[3]`. Now we know that `it1<it2`, and also know that `it2-it1==3`. This works exactly the same for iterators as it does for pointers, because iterators were modeled after pointers. The behavior of an iterator is identical to that of a pointer if what you are iterating over is a contiguous array. Iterators only differ from a pointer when they apply to other data structures.